# @EnvironmentObject Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an EnvironmentObject that I want to use as a datasource for my button title:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showDetailsView = false
    @EnvironmentObject var storage: Storage

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.doSomethingAsync()
                }) {
                    Text($storage.buttonTitle) // won't compile here
```

[image]

Here is my storage object:

```
class Storage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var buttonTitle: String
    @Published var dataObject: DataObject
    init(dataObject: DataObject = DataObject(name: "Test")) {
        self.dataObject = dataObject
        buttonTitle = "Try"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Text` takes in a `String` not a `Binding<String>`. Replace the line you pointed out with the following:

```
Text(storage.buttonTitle)
```